# Nutch 1.9 and Javascript generated content

Tags: selenium, ant, nutch

I am using Nutch 1.9.

When most of the web page is generated with javascript, Nutch ignores Javascripte generated content. Is it possible to fetch it too?

I've found Selenium could be a way to do it, but it seems it is supported only by Nutch 2.x. Is it possible to integrated (and how) with Nutch 1.9?

I've followed the installation instructions on [nutch-selenium](https://github.com/momer/nutch-selenium), but a lot's of errors occurred (obviously) when I ran ant.

```
compile:
     [echo] Compiling plugin: protocol-selenium
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to $NUTCH_HOME/build/protocol-selenium/classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/protocol-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/Http.java:14: error: package org.apache.nutch.storage does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.nutch.storage.WebPage;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/protocol-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/Http.java:15: error: package org.apache.nutch.storage.WebPage does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.nutch.storage.WebPage.Field;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/protocol-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/Http.java:26: error: package WebPage does not exist
    [javac]   private static final Collection<WebPage.Field> FIELDS = new HashSet<WebPage.Field>();
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac] $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/protocol-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/Http.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     protected Response getResponse(URL url, WebPage page, boolean redirect)
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class WebPage
    [javac]   location: class Http
    [javac] $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/protocol-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/Http.java:55: error: package WebPage does not exist
    [javac]   public Collection<WebPage.Field> getFields() {
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/protocol-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/HttpResponse.java:16: error: package org.apache.nutch.storage does not exist
    [javac] import org.apache.nutch.storage.WebPage;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/protocol-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/HttpResponse.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public HttpResponse(Http http, URL url, WebPage page, Configuration conf) throws ProtocolException, IOException {
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class WebPage
    [javac]   location: class HttpResponse
    [javac] $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/protocol-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/Http.java:26: error: package WebPage does not exist
    [javac]   private static final Collection<WebPage.Field> FIELDS = new HashSet<WebPage.Field>();
    [javac]                                                                              ^
    [javac] $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/protocol-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/Http.java:29: error: package WebPage does not exist
    [javac]     FIELDS.add(WebPage.Field.MODIFIED_TIME);
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac] $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/protocol-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/Http.java:30: error: package WebPage does not exist
    [javac]     FIELDS.add(WebPage.Field.HEADERS);
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac] $NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/protocol-selenium/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/selenium/Http.java:54: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]   @Override
    [javac]   ^
    [javac] 11 errors
    [javac] 1 warning

BUILD FAILED
$NUTCH_HOME/build.xml:112: The following error occurred while executing this line:
$NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/build.xml:77: The following error occurred while executing this line:
$NUTCH_HOME/src/plugin/build-plugin.xml:133: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Or are there any other options?

Comment: Hi, I wrote the Nutch-selenium plugin; you'll have to go in and change the structure a bit to make it work with older versions since the API for Nutch has changed some.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the plugin for Nutch 2.x (It's in the question), but I am new to Nutch so this seems to be a problem for me to do.